# How to pass XML as a tree using Document in Java

Tags: java, xml, tree

I have Defined own tree in own data structure like this:

```
class MyTree {
   String value;
   List<MyTree > childs = new ArrayList<>();

   //geters and seters...
}
```

Example tree:

```
     document 
        |
       item
  |           |
animal      people
  |           |  
 name       gender
```

Now, i have recursion method for iterate over my tree...

```
public void traverseTree(MyTree tree) {
        int childCount = tree.childs .size();
        if (childCount == 0) {
            // leaf node, we're done
        } else {
          for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
                traverseTree(tree.childs[i]);
          }
        }
}
```

So.. then I have

Loaded xml in program:

```
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlData.getBytes("UTF-8"))); //where xmlData is xml in String..
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
```

And I want print nodes, which are only in my data structure `MyTree`.

I don't know what methods user over `Document` can you help me please?

Thank you for your reply.

Edit: `MyTree` is created from xml (`xmlData`) in the past..

Comment: how is MyTree and the xml document related in any way? you don't show this

Comment: Sorry... MyTree is created from xml (xmlData) in the past..

Comment: so you are trying to print LanguageNode objects? what are they?

Comment: No, I am trying print all nodes from LanguageNode which are in `Document `. So I am validating document using own tree - LanguageNode